# Class in file added to eager load paths not being loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created the folder `app/classes`, and added the file RedcarpetHeaderDowngrade.rb to that folder. It contains the following class:

```
class RedcarpetHeaderDowngrade < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def header(text, level)
    level += 1
    "<h#{level}>#{text}</h#{level}>"
  end
end
```

In `config.application.rb` I have added the following line inside the `Application` class:

```
config.eager_load_paths += %W( #{config.root}/app/classes )
```

I am expecting this to make the `RedcarpetHeaderDowngrade.rb` file, thus making the class `RedcarpetHeaderDowngrade` available in my application. Indeed, this is working with a subfolder I created in the models directory and added to the eager load paths in the exact same way. However, the class `RedcarpetHeaderDowngrade` isn't getting loaded. I keep getting the error `uninitialized constant RedcarpetHeaderDowngrade`, whether I try it out in the console or on a page that calls that class.

Comment: Firstly the file should be named `redcarpet_header_downgrade.rb` to remain in the convention of `Rails`. Not doing so will create errors like `Uninitialized Constant ... expected ... to define it`. For monkey_patches which seems to be what you are trying to do here I would suggest rather than a file in `app/classes` why not just place it in `config/initializers` this way it will be loaded and initialized with the application and no need to modify the load path.

Comment: Yep, renaming the file did it. And I can see why initializers is a more logical place for this sort of thing. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your request: In `Rails` file naming is very important if you have a class like `RedcarpetHeaderDowngrade` then rails will look for a file that is named `redcarpet_header_downgrade.rb` to define this class.

If you attempt to call this class with the wrong file name you will get an error similar to `Uninitialized Constant ... expected ... to define it`. This is because `Rails` expects the class name to also designate the file as a snake_cased version of the class name, this means you replace the uppercase letters with downcased version and add a preceding underscore. Thus `redcarpet_header_downgrade.rb`.

That being said if you are monkey patching a class I would suggest adding this to `config/initializers` and leaving the load path alone. This way the class or patch is automatically loaded with the app itself. Leave adding things to the load path for full blown classes and functionality not handled by classes that are already loaded.